# After turning off/on the HDMI connected monitor/TV, there's no picture

Tags: windows-7, display, hdmi, htpc, eee-pc

I've recently connected an EeeBox 1501 to my LCD TV in order to utilize the computer as an HTPC.

If I switch off the TV or just change the input source, after turning on the TV back on or switch back to the PC's HDMI input, there's no picture.

The computer runs Windows 7. My previous HTPC, an Acer Aspire iDea 500 had no such problems running first Windows XP, and later Vista.

The PC runs fine and outputs sound all the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this thread: [Utility to turn off laptop display](https://superuser.com/questions/239498/utility-to-turn-off-laptop-display)

By using the .net based utility, I can switch on/off the screen. That makes the LCD TV to come back on after it has been turned off with the remote.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a video driver bug. Try latest drivers. I had similar problems with my monitor. A driver update (several months and updates later) eventually fixed it.