# Utility to turn off laptop display

Tags: laptop, display

laptop: Alienware M17x

I am using <kbd>win</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> to switch to projector only to turn off display (it's a tricky way, since there's no projector connected). And by press and key to turn on display.

Since the <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> (suspend mode) seems not only turn off display, but also turn off hard drive and something else. And I can't find a way to configure it to only turn off display.

I was wondering if anyone has a better way to turn on/off display? By using a utility? Or configure the suspend mode (how, though). Please advise, thanks.

Comment: If I do win+p / projector only, an error message appears and the screen lights back on : `No projector was detected`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A quick google search pointed me towards this small (~85kB) [utility](http://www.redmondpie.com/turn-off-your-notebook-lcd-with-one-click/). It works fine in Win7 for me, but it requires .net framework.

Answer (score 5):

[Display Power Off Utility:](http://doff.sf.net)

> Display power off utility. Allows to power off desktop/notebook
>   display and optionally lock workstation. Useful for keeping display's
>   USB hub active while display is in power save mode.

- Turns off monitor to save power or launches screensaver.
- Optionally locks workstation.
- Small and does not require installation or any additional frameworks.
- x64 build is available.
- Highly configurable. Details: doff /?

To simplify usage create desktop shortcut and assign hotkey.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a 1-KiB program that does that... no .NET Framework or anything else needed. :)

The source code is literally 3 lines:

```
#include <windows.h>
int main(void)
{ return SendMessage(GetShellWindow(), WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_MONITORPOWER, 2) != 0;}
```

Base64 encoding of executable:

```
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
```

Comment: Invalid or deleted file

Comment: @pinouchon: Ah, shoot. :( See my updated answer.